# How to Implement a Non Springboot Utility into a Springboot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I inherited the maintenance work on a Springboot program that currently dumps a number of debugging logs every time the application experiences an error (which could include incorrect queries within the UI itself). These log files are never deleted by the software, so they continually build up until they eventually fill up the server computer.

I've built a utility to manage these logs by deleting them once the log files reach 7 days of age. Admittedly, I'm still familiarizing myself with Springboot, so I built this utility externally. I looked at the program structure of the software, and it only uses a single main class as I expected, but the class only contains a call to run the Springboot API in addition to a couple of beans. My question is, in general, where in the Springboot structure should I look to implement my code?

Here's what I'm seeking to add for context:

```
package com.climatedev.test;
//Import packages
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.Date;

public class CleanLogs {

    //Create static array that will hold all files in the path
    public static File[] files;

    //Give the program the path of the log files to delete
    private void getPath() {
        File file = new File("C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Data");
        String id = "CW-LANDCAST-bin";
        files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                return name.startsWith(id);
            }
        });
    }
    //Delete all files older than 7 days
    private void deleteLogs() {
        getPath();
         for(File f : files) {
             long diff = new Date().getTime() - f.lastModified();
             if (diff > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
                 f.delete();
             }
         }
     }

    //Call the clean files program (testing purposes only)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CleanLogs obj = new CleanLogs();
        obj.deleteLogs();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to build your own utility for log management. Check first is that app using any loging library like logback or log4j. If they are present change its configuration to manage your logs.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Comment: This is _best_ handled externally like you did. _However_, you could also use `@Scheduled`.